# How do I unhide a message group in phone link in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, links, phone

I have my Google SmartPhone set up to link to my PC's Windows 11 desktop using phone Link. I was hiding messages by selecting the ellipsis beside the message and clicking hide. I accidentally selected a group I still want. It has a long message chain and I did not want to lose it. I cannot find an unhide feature. The group is still on my phone but no longer appears on my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

In the Phone Link desktop app, at the top of the message list, there should be "Recent >" at the top as a heading. You can collapse the messages by clicking on that button, or scroll the message pane to the bottom, and you should see a "Hidden >" which can be expanded, if it's not already.  Inside that group, your hidden contact should be visible, and you can use the "..." menu to access Unhide.  Boom, they go back into the Recent category.  I just had the same issue, and found the answer after seeing this thread had no answers.